# Selecting for the absence of value in a one-to-many table design

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been working all day on a problem that I expected to be simple, but is proving incredibly elusive. I suspect I may not be asking the right questions, so please bear with me.

I have a table with a bunch of newspaper articles for a research project. The idea is that researchers can tag individual articles. These tags are stored in a second table. An article can have any number of tags.

I can then select articles with a certain tag by using;

```
SELECT *, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`TAGS`.`TAG`) AS tags 
FROM   ARTICLES 
       LEFT JOIN TAGS 
               ON TAGS.ID = ARTICLES.ID 
WHERE  TAGS.TAG = 'search term' 
GROUP  BY ARTICLES.ID;
```

My problems start when I want to select articles based on the absence of a particular tag. If an article has only one tag, the result is as expected, but if there is more then one tag associated with an article, the tag is simply ommitted.

```
SELECT *, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`TAGS`.`TAG`) AS tags 
FROM   ARTICLES 
       LEFT JOIN TAGS 
               ON TAGS.ID = ARTICLES.ID 
WHERE  TAGS.TAG != 'search term' 
        OR TAGS.TAG IS NULL 
GROUP  BY ARTICLES.ID;
```

if the original tables where as follows;

```
ID               Name
1                Article #1
2                Article #2
```

and;

```
ArticleID        Tag
1                New
1                Long
1                Boring
2                Old
2                Long
2                Interesting
```

Then if I use the above query to select articles where tag != Boring, the results would be;

```
ArticleID        Name          Tags
1                Article #1    New, Long
2                Article #2    Old, Long, Interesting
```

How can I make it exclude the first article altogether, rather then just excluding that tag? Keeping in mind that there are over a hundred thousand articles in the database, what is the most efficient way to do this? I've looked at dozens of other questions and google searches, but selecting for the absence of a tag like this is something I could not find advice on.

On a sidenote, I am currently using a one-to-many table, as each tag appears once for each article it is linked to. I noticed that a lot of people in similar scenarios use a many-to-many design. Is this that much faster then having just a foreign key in the tags table referencing the article table?

Thank you for helping out an SQL noob :).

Comment: LEFT JOIN... ON x = x AND y = y WHERE y IS NULL;

Comment: Right, this is the result of me staring for hours. The SQL I was using uses left joins already, typo in here.

Comment: @Strawberry, I still don't understand where you're going with this though. What do x and y represent in this?

Comment: ON TAGS.ID = ARTICLES.ID 
AND TAGS.TAG = 'search term'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  A.ID, 
        A.`Name`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`TAGS`.`TAG`) AS tags 
FROM   ARTICLES A
       LEFT JOIN TAGS 
               ON TAGS.ID = A.ID 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TAGS 
                    WHERE ID = A.ID
                    AND Tag = 'search term')
GROUP  BY ARTICLES.ID, ARTICLES.`Name`;
```

Comment: After deleting the tags.tag = 'search term', this appears to work. I'm going to play around with it a bit more and then come back to select the answer.

Comment: @Fluffy Yeah, sorry, that was bad copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`TAGS`.`TAG`) AS tags 
FROM   ARTICLES A
       LEFT JOIN TAGS 
           ON TAGS.ID = ARTICLES.ID 
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ArticleID FROM TAGS
    WHERE Tag = 'search term'
)
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Comment: is this personal preference, or is IN faster than EXISTS?

Comment: Personal knowledge actually, I didn't know `EXISTS` could be used in this way (only know it in the context of if a table exists). Did some reading on it and my guess would be that `EXISTS` might actually be faster because you're not comparing A.ID with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.ID, 
        A.`Name`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`TAGS`.`TAG`) AS tags 
FROM   ARTICLES A
       LEFT JOIN TAGS 
 ON TAGS.ID = A.ID 

LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT ArticleID FROM TAGS LKP
    WHERE Tag = 'search term'
) SRCH
 ON SRCH. ArticleID =A.ID
WHERE SRCH. ArticleID IS NUll
```